# Error conectándome a MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Estoy haciendo un `select` a mi base de datos. El código que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost',
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'base_prueba'
mysql = MySQL(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM periodo")
rv = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
```

Y quiero mostra los datos en una tabla. Me arroja el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: connect() argument 1 must be str, not tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es esta línea:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost',
```

¿Puedes notar la coma al final? Con esto estás haciendo pensar a Python que es una tupla:

```
>>> variable = 'hola'
>>> type(variable)
<class 'str'>
>>> variable = 'hola',
>>> type(variable)
<class 'tuple'>
```

¿Notas la diferencia?

Con esto te das cuenta de que la conexión a MySQL está recibiendo una tupla y no una cadena de texto como debería ser. La solución es muy sencilla, elimina la coma al final:

```
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
```

Lo que pasa es que las tuplas se representan con paréntesis en Python y la sintaxis para representar una tupla de **un** elemento es poniendo una coma al final. Observa:

```
>>> variable = ('hola')
>>> type(variable)
<class 'str'>
```

¿Qué pasó? Python está evaluando el contenido del paréntesis, que ciertamente es un `str`, para poder diferenciarlo de la tupla de un elemento entonces se usa la coma:

```
>>> variable = ('hola',)
>>> type(variable)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Y lo anterior es sintácticamente igual a esto:

```
>>> variable = 'hola',
>>> type(variable)
<class 'tuple'>
```

De hecho, puedes crear una tupla con más elementos sin usar paréntesis:

```
>>> variable = 'hola', 10, True
>>> type(variable)
<class 'tuple'>
```

Python es muy inteligente ;-)